# userdel still keeps users in /etc/passwd?

Tags: users

I made a shell script that deletes an unix user and among other things, here the command used to delete the user :

```
pkill -9 -u `id -u {USERNAME}` > /dev/null 2>&1
userdel -f -r {USERNAME} > /dev/null 2>&1
rm -rf /home/{USERNAME} > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The folder is correctly removed, but if I go to the /etc/passwd, I can still see the user in the file.

I tried the `userdel` command manually and there was no errors.

What am I missing? (I can show any log if you need them, I just didn't find any odd things)

**Note:** If I do this command (`userdel`) manually for the users already deleted, they are correctly removed from the `/etc/passwd` file. This seems to indicate that when it's being called by the script, it fails for some reasons.

Comment: What happens when you don't silence the output?

Comment: I'd like to know! :p It's being run by a cron task at specifics moment for specific users :/

Comment: I mean, you're the one who silenced it, so you can try not silencing it: remove `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @CyrilN.: You can redirect the output to some regular file instead of `/dev/null` to be able to check for errors.